# API call works locally, but fails when deployed to Heroku or zeit

Tags: javascript, http, heroku, axios

The HTTP GET call works fine locally, but fails when the app is deployed to Heroku or zeit.

Here is the code:

```
const searchUrl = "https:/hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=" + searchTerm;
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: searchUrl,
      responseType: "json"
    })
```

I'm making a call to Hackernews API. But when I open network tab while loading the app in heroku, I see it is making the call to `https://evening-chamber-42563.herokuapp.com/hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=` (the actual url should be `https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=`), somehow it is inserting `evening-chamber-42563.herokuapp.com/` in between the actual URL that I've specified.

I thought it might be a problem with heroku, and deployed my app on zeit to see if it fixes the issue. Same thing again. This time it made a request to `https://hackernews-clone-bgbmdyblch.now.sh/hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=` (`hackernews-clone-bgbmdyblch.now.sh` is where my app is deployed).

I tried with native fetch, and axios library. Still same issue.

Hours of google searching didn't help me, so I'm posting this here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was a typo in the URL (missing a '/' after the protocol). It worked fine after correcting it.

When I called `fetch` in my localhost with the incorrect URL (missing '/'), the browser corrected it for me. But it created problems when the app was deployed on a cloud platform.